# I have an idea how you could crack the keys in RSA

Tags: rsa

Hello everyone on the forum,
I'd like to give you an idea of ​​how the keys in RSA could be cracked.
I am a passionate amateur and I do not know if this idea makes sense, but I would like to present it.

I would like to start from the beginning to describe the idea in an understandable way.
We know what RSA numbers are - it's the product of two primes, so all numbers that are divisible by 2, 3 and 5 are definitely not going to be an RSA key.
The remaining numbers 7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31 ... .. etc. is a sequence of prime or composite numbers.
What happens when we start ordering these numbers like this:

1. 7 + 30 = 37, 37 + 30 = 67, 67 + 30 = 97 etc.,
2. 11 + 30 = 41, 41 + 30 = 71, 71 + 30 = 101 etc.,
3. 13 + 30 = 43, 43 + 30 = 73, 73 + 30 = 103 etc.,
4. 17 + 30 = 47, 47 + 30 = 77, 77 + 30 = 107 etc.,
5. 19 + 30 = 49, 49 + 30 = 79, 79 + 30 = 109 etc.,
6. 23 + 30 = 53, 53 + 30 = 83, 83 + 30 = 113 etc.,
7. 29 + 30 = 59, 59 + 30 = 89, 89 + 30 = 119 etc.,
8. 31 + 30 = 61, 61 + 30 = 91, 91 + 30 = 121 etc.,

Thanks to this view, we have a set of all primes and complex numbers, divided into groups from 1 to 8.
If we divide these numbers in groups by 30 the result will be (xxxx, mod)
Group:

1. 7/30 = 0.2 (3), 37/30 = 1.2 (3) etc.,
2. 11/30 = 0.3 (6), 41/30 = 1.3 (6) etc.,
3. 13/30 = 0.4 (3), 43/30 = 1.4 (3) etc.,
4. 17/30 = 0.5 (6), 47/30 = 1.5 (6) etc.,
5. 19/30 = 0.6 (3), 49/30 = 1.6 (3) etc.,
6. 23/30 = 0.7 (6), 53/30 = 1.7 (6) etc.,
7. 29/30 = 0.9 (6), 59/30 = 1.9 (6) etc.,
8. 31/30 = 1.0 (3) 61/30 = 1.0 (3) etc.,

What did it do? This gave us that we could assign a prime number or RSA to the appropriate group.

Example:

37 * 101 = 3737/30 = 124.5 (6) - group 4.

79 * 107 = 8453/30 = 281.7 (6) - group 6

Now we will start looking at these groups and, for easier understanding, we will set ourselves a very small number of RSAs, e.g .:
1035071 - this is the product of the number 947 · 1093

We divide this number 1035071 by 30 and get 34502.3 (6)

34502.3 (6) - We know this is group "2" starting with "11,41,71 …… etc" so we focus on this group.
After writing down these numbers (11, 41, 71 ... etc.) and dividing the "whole group" by the numbers, I got a relationship again, namely:
All the numbers in group 11 divided by 7 ... + 30 .. gives us the result 23 .. + 30 ...
E.g.

161/7 = 23,851 / 37 = 23

371/7 = 53 1961/37 = 53

581/7 = 83 3071/37 = 83
Etc.

And the same is true when we divide the numbers from the group "2" by 31 ... + 30 .. we get 11 ... + 30 ..
the same when we divide the numbers from the group "2" by 13 .... + 30 ... we get 17 ... + 30 ..
the same when we divide the numbers from the group "2" by 19 ... + 30, we get 29 .. + 30 ..
It cannot be otherwise because after multiplying the number 53 * 29 = 1537/30 = 51.2 (3,) and this is a different group - group "1".
All numbers in group "2" that cannot be divided by numbers in the remaining groups are prime numbers.
So we know that
group "2" is 11+ (30 * n) consists of four calculation possibilities, namely:

If the group 11+ (30 * n) is divisible by 7+ (30 * n) we get 23+ (30 * n),
If the group 11+ (30 * n) is divisible by 31+ (30 * n), we get 11+ (30 * n),
If the group 11+ (30 * n) is divisible by 13+ (30 * n) we get 17+ (30 * n),
If the group 11+ (30 * n) is divisible by 19+ (30 * n) we get 19+ (30 * n),
If it does not meet these assumptions, then it is the prime number in this group "2".

We can shorten the calculations even further.
We divide the number of RSA by 30 we get a group. We remove "mod" and divide by 30 again, which causes us to get groups again.
I think you can create an appropriate algorithm for the calculations. I only work with a calculator and Excel, so analysis and calculations for large numbers is beyond my reach. Is it possible to build an algorithm that breaks the RSA keys on the basis of such a distribution?
Thank you very much

Comment: Exploring math and cryptography is great but don't spend too much time trying to crack RSA. There's a reason why plenty of people have tried and no one has succeeded in decades.

Comment: If something is unpredictable, it is only because we lack information. There is always a theory to explain randomness, it only takes time to discover it.

Comment: Actually, Quantum Mechanics states that there is true randomness (not that this applies in this scenario).  In any case, lots of really bright people have studied the factorization problem; the best anyone's come up with in the general case (without a Quantum Computer) is NFS (difficulty based on the size of the number being factored) and ECM (difficulty based on the size of the smallest prime factor) - it appears quite unlikely that you'd uncover anything that hasn't already been explored.

Comment: Please understand that I'm trying my best to say this in a nice way, but you haven't discovered anything new. Your time would be better spent gaining more advanced knowledge rather than trying to crack RSA with math that has been well-understood for hundreds of years. You have to be familiar with the current state of the art before trying to advance it.

Answer (score 4):

> Hello everyone on the forum

Actually, this is not a forum, this is a Question and Answer site, where people ask questions (about cryptography, see other stackexchanges for other topics) and other people answer them.

However, you did ask a question at the end:

> Is it possible to build an algorithm that breaks the RSA keys on the basis of such a distribution?

Doesn't look likely.  You divide the integers (that are not divisible by 2, 3, 5) into 8 equivalence classes (that's the term mathematicians use, in this case, two values $x, y$ belong to the same equivalence class if they are the same value modulo 30), and try to use the fixed multiplicative relations between the class of $N$ (the product) and the potential classes of $P, Q$ (the unknown primes).

The problem is that this relation doesn't allow you to eliminate any possible class as something that $P, Q$ might belong to; for any known class $N$ and a potential class $P$, there will be a class that $Q$ would belong to that is consistent with those class assumptions.  For example, if $N$ is group 2 (which we would write as $11 \bmod 30$, or just 11), then $P$ could also be group 2 (11) if $Q$ happened to be group 8 (which we would write as 1, as that equivalance class consists of values $1 \bmod 30$).

When you write "All numbers in group "2" that cannot be divided by numbers in the remaining groups are prime numbers", I presume you meant that you wrote out the possibilities and discounted them - that strategy doesn't scale to RSA-size values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Poncho. Thank you also for making me (rightly) aware of the existence and purpose of this website. I have done some work with RSA numbers and would like to present it. Poncho is it possible to present work on RSA numbers via e-meil or some other way?